# Difference between function myName() and var myName = function() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, declaration

Is there any difference between declaring a Javascript function like this:

```
function myName(...)
```

and like this:

```
var myName = function(...)
```

I don't believe so, but...

Comment: The first is a declaration and has a name, the second is an expression which you haven't given a name :)

Comment: This has been asked and answered here on SO at *least* a dozen times.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ...per day

Answer (score 1):

The **first** is a *function declaration*
You have given it a name.
It will be hoisted.

The **second** is a *function expression*
The way you wrote it, it's anonymous.
It will only be available after the line where it is defined.

Comment: I cringe at the term hoisted... why is such terminology not used in other languages

Comment: @Esailija you might see it called "loop-invariant code" or "scalar promotion" when talking about other languages. It's usually something the compiler does as an optimisation.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. It means something **entirely different** in any other language. E.g. you don't say a method is hoisted in Java when you are able to call it before it's declaration, that would be ridiculous but in Javascript it's ok to confuse these terms (hoisting applies as its actual meaning as well when discussing optimizations in javascript) :P </rant>

Comment: @Esailija it's the same process, it's just _JavaScript's_ compilers tend to be less "smart" and therefore what it happens to is more obvious and more relevant when coding for it. "Hoisted" just happened to be the word that caught to describe it, probably because it gets mentioned a little more often in _JavaScript_ than other languages, and the others are longer to remember/say.

Comment: multipass compilation and hoisting are not the same process at all, if that's what you imply